# Accessing couchdb of windows pc from ubuntu pc via pouchdb

Tags: windows, ip, couchdb, pouchdb

So what I've been attempting is to copy a couchdb database from my windows PC to my Ubuntu laptop, using pouchdb. But I am having trouble accessing the couchdb database. No matter what I try, I get a "`getCheckpoint rejected with`" error. Bind address is set to 0.0.0.0 and no firewall should be in the way. If you have any idea how to do it, any tips would be helpful. As I am quite new to networking, a good background reading source would be appreciated as well.

Here's my (convoluted) code:

```
var local_db = new PouchDB('buildings');
var remoteCouch = 'http://localhost:5984/buildings';
var arne_db = 'http://<133.34.253.53>:5984/buildings/';

function replicate() {
  local_db.replicate.from(arne_db).on('complete', function () {
      console.log("Replicated from Arne");
    local_db.replicate.to(remoteCouch).on('complete', function () {
        console.log("Replicated to remote_local");
      }).on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("Failed to replicate remote_local");
        console.log(err);
    });
    }).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log("Failed to replicate Arne");
      console.log(err);
      console.log(err.other_errors);
  });

}

if (arne_db){
  replicate();
} else {
  console.log("No connection to arne_db");
}
```

Comment: I think I see two couchdbs here. Which is giving the error?

Comment: The one called arne_db, when i try to replicate from it.